# mysql если совпадает весь список

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы. Нужно сделать выборку при условии что есть полное совпадение по ключам.

Таблица постов(posts)

```
id  object_id  title
1       10     name1
2       20     name2
3       30     name3
4       40     name4
```

Таблица категорий(category)

```
id  post_id  category
1      1        car
2      1        bed
3      1        bird
4      2        car
5      3        car
6      3        bed
7      3        home
8      4        car
9      4        home
```

При условии category = car, bed нужно получить только пост с id 1 и 3

---

**UPDATE** (скопировано из комментария)

> "VERSION()": "5.6.36-1~dotdeb+7.1" – Дмитрий Бабанин

Comment: Т.е. Вы задаёте параметр `category = 'car'` и затем выбираете все пары, у которых присутствует указанный атрибут и полностью совпадает набор атрибутов, верно? Тогда вопрос - нужны именно пары? или целиком группа? ведь таких совпадающих по полному набору групп может быть несколько, с разными количеством постов в группе и с разными наборами... как должен выглядеть результат? PS. Для решаемой задачи таблица `posts` не нужна вообще.

Comment: да. нужно именно что бы присутствовала эта пара в одном посте. категорий у поста может быть больше. Это сортировка получается по категориям. Показывать только те посты у кого есть эти категории

Comment: "VERSION()": "5.6.36-1~dotdeb+7.1"

Comment: вопрос поправил должен вернуть только 1 и 3 пост. PS к сожалению нужна

Comment: *PS к сожалению нужна* Так её потом приджойнить, во внешнем запросе, как бы не проблема...

Comment: Это да. так и планируется. Там еще куча дополнительных параметров фильтрации. Я просто надеялся что может есть на подобие IN метод какой. Просто категорий будет очень много да и добавляются они из админки

Comment: Нет встроенных методов сравнения групп записей. Но сама задача - хорошее основание, чтобы подумать об обновлении версии MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category ORDER BY category) cat_list
          FROM category
          GROUP BY post_id
          HAVING SUM(category = 'car') ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT cat_list
          FROM cte1
          GROUP BY cat_list
          HAVING COUNT(cat_list) > 1 )
SELECT post_id, cat_list
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (cat_list)
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48814300466e6ab6b6861cf40a6558c7)

Для версии 5.x это будет выглядеть так:

```sql
SELECT post_id, cat_list
FROM ( SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category ORDER BY category) cat_list
       FROM category
       GROUP BY post_id
       HAVING SUM(category = 'car') ) cte1
JOIN ( SELECT cat_list
       FROM ( SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category ORDER BY category) cat_list
              FROM category
              GROUP BY post_id
              HAVING SUM(category = 'car') ) cte1
       GROUP BY cat_list
       HAVING COUNT(cat_list) > 1 ) cte2 USING (cat_list)
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=83fb1d3ded486957623ba29a8ddd848c)

Если нужно - добавьте в источник данных внешнего запроса и таблицу `posts`, соответствующим образом откорректировав список полей вывода.

Comment: спасибо. буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо получить только первое совпадение, можно использовать LIMIT

```
SELECT posts.*  
FROM posts 
JOIN categories ON categories.post_id = posts.id 
WHERE categories.category IN ("car","bed") 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Нет не первое. постов может быть много с таким списком категорий.

Comment: Ну тогда не LIMIT 1. Но я тогда не понимаю, в чем именно трудность запроса?